# PHP T_Public syntax error?

Tags: php, syntax

I can't figure out what's causing this error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_PUBLIC

It says the error is occuring on the second line of this code `(public function upload($uid = 'public')`.

```
//--> Uploads the file
public function upload($uid = 'public')
{

//Get file details
if(isset($_GET['ajax']))
{
if(!$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FILE_SIZE'] > 0) return false;

$filename = strip_tags($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FILE_NAME']);
$file_type = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FILE_TYPE'];
$size = round($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FILE_SIZE']/1000, 3);
}
else
{
if($_FILES["files"]["error"] > 0 or empty($_FILES)) return false;

$filename = strip_tags($_FILES['files']['name']);
$file_type = $_FILES['files']['type'];
$size = round($_FILES['files']['size']/1000, 3);
}

//FF null type fix
if( $file_type == null || strlen($file_type) == 0 ) $file_type = "unknown";

//Reduce filename to < 255 char
if(strlen( $filename ) > 255 )
{
$filename = urldecode($filename);
$filename = substr($filename, 0, 36) . '--.' . pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$filename = urlencode($filename);
}

//Check file size
if($size > (maxFileSize/1000))
{
$this->errorMessage = "file too large";
return false;
}

//Check file type
if( limitFileTypes and !in_array($file_type, explode(',', allowedFileTypes)) )
{
$this->errorMessage = "file type not allowed";
return false;
}

$db = $this->connectDB();

$share = isset($_GET['ajax'])?$_SERVER['HTTP_BITDROPSHARE']:$_POST['bitdrop_share'];
$share = ($share == 'true' || $share == 'share' )? 1 : 0;

$password = isset($_GET['ajax'])?$_SERVER['HTTP_BITDROPPASS']:$_POST['bitdrop_password'];

//Find an available shortURL
$res = $db->prepare("select count(shortURL) from share where binary shortURL = ?;");
do
{
$shortURL = $this->shortURL();
$res->execute(array($shortURL));
$data = $res->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN, 0);
}
while($data[0] != 0);

$password = ( is_null($password) or strlen($password)==0 ) ? 0 : sha1($password . $shortURL) ;

$q = "insert into details (date, name, size, type, public, password) values (now(), ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
$data = array($filename, $size, $file_type, $share, $password);
$res = $db->prepare($q);

//exec command or print error
if(!$res->execute($data)) print_r($db->errorInfo());

$fid = $db->lastInsertId();

$q = "insert into share (shortURL, file_id) values (?, ?)";
$data = array($shortURL, $fid);
$res = $db->prepare($q);
$res->execute($data);

//Connect unique user to file
$tid = $this->addTag("_$uid");

$q = "insert into `fid-tid` (file_id, tag_id) values ('$fid', '$tid');";
$res = $db->prepare($q);
$res->execute();

$file = $_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT] . "/uploads/$fid.temp";

$this->log('upload', '{ "uid" : "'.$uid.'", "fid" : "'.$fid.'", "shortURL" : "'.$shortURL.'" }');

$db = null;

//Upload file
if(isset($_GET['ajax']))
{
if(!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FILE_NAME']) && !isset($_SERVER['CONTENT_LENGTH']))
{
$this->errorMessage = "no headers found";
return false;
}

$fileReader = fopen('php://input', "r");
$fileWriter = fopen($file, "w+");

while(true)
{   
$buffer = fgets($fileReader, 4096);
if(strlen($buffer) == 0)
{
fclose($fileReader);
fclose($fileWriter);
$this->createThumb($fid, $shortURL);
$this->shortURL = $shortURL;
return true;
}
fwrite($fileWriter, $buffer);
}
}
else
{
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["files"]["tmp_name"], $file);
$this->createThumb($fid, $shortURL);
$this->shortURL = $shortURL;
return true;
}
}
```

Comment: Yikes! What happened to your indentation? `:-)`

Comment: Next time, see if you can make a minimal example. In your case, you could have made an example like this: `public function test(){ echo 'test';}` .. You'd still get the error and the question would be much clearer. The answer wouldn't be more interesting ofcourse, as the 'public' is not allowed there, but it would be a good step to asking better questions :)

Comment: Seems like classic partial copy+pasting (though could be a number of other syntax issues). Origin, btw: `bitdrop.class.php - v1.4`.

Answer (score 2):

You are defining function `public`.

The `public` is a keyword for Object Orieneted Programming.

But, as per your code, there is no class defined, therefore, there is no use `public` keyword.

Just remove the `public` keyword.

Corrected code:

```
function upload($uid = 'public')
```

Comment: Not only `I think you are defining function public`, he does it :D